# Configure Apache Directories

Tags: apache, configuration, directory, location

I have a problem in configuring my Apache. This litte indian is something headstrong.

My Application is located under /var/www/myapp/

There are 3 Elements:

```
./index.cgi - a python cgi script correctly working
./Application/ - a directory, which should be not public. contains include packages for index.cgi
./Public/ - a directory, public. contains javascripts, css files, images e.q.
```

My current VirtualHost configuration looks like:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/
Alias /Public/* "/var/www/myapp/Public/*"
<Location "/myapp/*">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
ScriptAlias "/index.cgi" "/var/www/myapp/index.cgi"
```

So `/Public` is public as wished, index.cgi runs. But: /Application is accessible. How do I lock this directory?

Second thing is: index.cgi should run, when I call www.mydomain.com/ or www.mydomain.com/index.cgi. Nothing else but URI parameters. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance,
BigM

Comment: if you don't want something accessible, then don't put it inside your document root.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the permissions in the files, but I think that the problem is that you don't have an alias for the Application folder in your Apache Configuration File.